# Scala type mismatch when adding an element to an array

Tags: scala

I have the following array:

```
var as = Array.empty[Tuple2[Int, Int]]
```

I am adding an element to it like this:

```
var nElem = Tuple2(current, current)
as += nElem
```

`current` is a `var` of type `Int`

However, I am getting this error:

```
Solution.scala:51: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: String
                as += nElem
```

I don't understand why this is appearing. I haven't declared a `String` anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`+=` is the string concatenation operator.
You are looking for `:+` to append to an array. Note, that `Array` length is immutable, so `:+=`,  will return a new array, with the `nElem` appended, and assign it to the `as` variable, the original array will stay unchanged (take this as a hint, that you are likely doing something in a suboptimal way).

Note, that if you find yourself using `var`, that is almost always a sign of a bad design in your code. Mutable objects and variables are considered really bad taste in functional programming. Sometimes, you can't get away without using them, but those are rare corner cases. Most of the time, you should not need mutability.

Also, do not use `Tuple2`. Just do `Array.empty[(Int, Int)]`, `nElem = (current, current)` etc.

Comment: `Array` is not completely immutable, only it's `length` is immutable (as in Java). So effectively, you can neither append or remove, only replace current elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `:+=` to modify the variable in place. However, remember this: Using both `var` and a mutable data structure at the same time (like `Array`) is a sign of really bad programming. Either is sometimes fine, though.

However, note that this operation is O(n), therefore pushing n elements like that is going to be slow, O(n²). Arrays are not meant to have elements pushed to back like that. You can alternatively use a `var Vector` instead and call `.toArray()` on it at the end or use a mutable `val ArrayBuffer`. However, prefer functional style of programming, unless it produces less readable code.

Also, avoid typing `Tuple2` explicitly. Use `Array.empty[(Int, Int)]` and var `nElem = (current, current)`.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of `+` are weird because of the automatic conversion to `String` in certain cases. To append to an array, use the `:+` method:

```
as :+= nElem
```